# How to assemble apk from disassembled .smali file?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

Using [SmaliBaksmali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali), I disassembled an apk to .smali files and made some code changes.

```
baksmali disassemble app.apk -o app
```

How to assemble these .smali file to apk file?

Comment: You need to use APKTool if you want to decompile and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

build the apk using this command with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/):

`apktool.jar -f b <app-location> -o <output.apk>`

---

### 2.

Then sign the apk, you can use [uber-signer](https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer):

`uber-apk-signer.jar --debug -a <output.apk> --overwrite --allowResign`

---

### 3.

Install on device via `adb`:

`adb -d install <output.apk>`